Webflux functional with Open api v3 @schema type = array not working
I'm trying to create a functional spring boot spring webflux project that applies open api v3 but this seems quite difficult.
FunctionalConfig example:
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> baseTemplateMonoRouterFunction(TemplateHandler templateHandler) {
        return CoreUtilities.baseMonoRouterFunction(templateHandler, TemplateEntity.class, "/template");
    }

pom.xml
<!-- Spring doc ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

public static Consumer<Builder> getOpenApi(
            String tagName,
            String operationId,
            Class<?> classEntity,
            String summary
    ) {
        return ops -> ops.tag(tagName)
                .operationId(operationId).summary(summary).tags(new String[]{"Functional " + tagName})
                .security(org.springdoc.core.fn.builders.securityrequirement.Builder.securityRequirementBuilder().name(UtilitiesConstant.OpenApiSecurityName))
                .parameter(
                        parameterBuilder().in(ParameterIn.QUERY)
                                .name("roles")
                                .description("Role List")
                                .required(false)
                                .schema(
                                        org.springdoc.core.fn.builders.schema.Builder.schemaBuilder()
                                                .type("array")
                                )

                )
                .response(responseBuilder().responseCode("200").description("Successful operation").implementation(classEntity))
                .response(responseBuilder().responseCode("400").description("Invalid " + tagName + " ID supplied"))
                .response(responseBuilder().responseCode("401").description("Unauthorised"))
                .response(responseBuilder().responseCode("403").description("Forbidden"))
                .response(responseBuilder().responseCode("404").description(tagName + " not found"));
    }

Sample output:

I want to display query array add item as shown below

